# How to run one single IT test in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a project where there is just one class in src/test/java/SingleIT.java

This is not a unit-test, this IT test that set up database, launch tomcat embedded and etc.

How i can run it with the help of mvn?

**EDIT:**

I need maven configuration in pom.xml to run this

Answer (score 0):

Add a `profile` section to to your pom that links the test to a profile.

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>IT-Test</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
              <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/com/IT-Test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
              </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Then define your test in the usual way:

Something like:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="IT Tests" verbose="1">
         <test name="IT Test">
            <classes>
                <class name="com.xxx.SingleIT"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

Now whenever you want to run your test - pick the profile and run the app.

Comment: can it be more easily for just one test? can we skip suiteXmlFile?

Answer (score 0):

Running single test with surefire : http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html